# El chat para el otro usuario no aparece en su fragmento hasta que me contesta. Quiero que le aparezca aunque no me haya contestado

Tags: java, android, firebase

Mi app tiene un chat, y los usuarios pueden hablarse a través del chat. El problema que tengo que no sé cómo solucionarlo es que si es la primera vez que tu y yo hablamos, y si yo a ti te mando un mensaje el chat en mi fragmento si que aparece, pero en tu fragmento no aparece hasta que tu me contestas. Esto un problema porque quiero que el otro usuario reciba el chat / mensaje aunque no me haya contestado todavía.

Podría alguien decirme porqué no aparece el chat para el otro usuario hasta que me conteste y cómo puedo modificar el código para que le aparezca.

**MessageActivity**

```
private void sendMessage(String sender, final String receiver, String message) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");

        Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        String formattedDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(date);

        String time = null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            time = LocalTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));
        }

        String messageId = reference.push().getKey();

        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("sender", sender);
        hashMap.put("receiver", receiver);
        hashMap.put("message", message);
        hashMap.put("isseen", false);
        hashMap.put("date", formattedDate);
        hashMap.put("time", time);
        hashMap.put("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
        hashMap.put("messageId", messageId);

        if (messageId != null)
            reference.child(messageId).setValue(hashMap);

        final DatabaseReference chatref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chatlist").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).child(mId);
        chatref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    chatref.child("id").setValue(mId);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

**ChatsFragment**

```
private void chatList() {
    mUsers = new ArrayList<>();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mUsers.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    for (Chatlist chatlist : mUsersList) {
                        if (mFirebaseUser != null && user != null) {
                            if (!user.getId().equals(mFirebaseUser.getUid()) && user.getId().equals(chatlist.receiver)) {
                                mUsers.add(user);
                            } else if (chatlist.receiver.equals(mFirebaseUser.getUid())) {
                                mUsers.add(user);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                mUserAdapterChat = new UserAdapterChat(getContext(), mUsers, true);
                mUserAdapterChat.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mUserAdapterChat);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Mucho me temo que este tipo de librerias tan especificas no son dominadas por cualquiera.

Yo usé en su dia un chat, y no era tan complicado. Sólo hacía falta controlar la clase socket, sin librerías externas. Yo mandaba el texto plano, pero siempre podrías cifrarlo, ya que puedes extraer los bytes del mensaje y operar con ellos antes de enviarlos, para volver a operar con ellos al recibirlos, deshacer las operaciones y así obtener los bytes originales del mensaje para poder mostrarlos.

Sea como fuere, con librería o sin ella, un detalle sobre los if. Un if dentro de otro solo tiene sentido cuando en el interior del primer if hay algo más que el segundo if. De no haberlo, es mejor concatenar las condiciones y tener 1 único if.

```
int a=3;
if (a!=1){
 if (a!=2){
  system.out.println("Mi acción corresponde al cumplimiento de las 2 condiciones");
 }
}
```

es igual a:

```
int a=3;
if (a!=1 && a!=2){
 system.out.println("Mi acción corresponde al cumplimiento de las 2 condiciones");
}
```

pero es distinto a:

```
int a=3;
if (a!=1){
 if (a!=2){
  system.out.println("Esta acción corresponde al cumplimiento de las 2 condiciones");
 }
 system.out.println("Esta accion corresponde al cumplimiento de la condicion 1. " +
   "Independientemente de si se ha cumplido la condición 2 o no.");
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero para el chat no sabrías cómo lo puedo hacer funcionar? El ChatsFragmento lo he cambiado. Podrías echarle un vistazo?